# Input type password validity patternMismatch status is different to regex test result

Tags: javascript, html, regex, input, checkvalidity

I have a regex to check whether a string contains at least one digit, one lower case, and one upper case character.

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])
```

This evaluates to true with test strings such as '1aA'.

However the validity status of the patternMismatch does not evaluate in the same fashion as the regex test on the input elements value.

Is there a reason why the patternMismatch of an input would validate different to the regex test?

In the below snippet a class with associated background colour will be toggled depending on the result of the regex test. The invalid pseudo class should be true depending on the patternMismatch [according to the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState/patternMismatch).

```js
const password = document.getElementById("auth_user_password");

password.addEventListener("input", check);

function check() {
  /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/.test(password.value)
    ? password.classList.add("valid")
    : password.classList.remove("valid");
}
```

```css
:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.valid {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="auth_user_password" type="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])">
```

Comment: But the javascript test is the expected result and adding the caret ^ to the pattern doesn't change the behaviour to be the same as the JS .test result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set minimum charaters, then check it with `element.validity.valid`

```js
const password = document.getElementById("auth_user_password");

password.addEventListener("input", check);

function check() {
  password.validity.valid ?
    password.classList.add("valid") :
    password.classList.remove("valid");
}
```

```css
input:invalid {border: 3px solid red;}
.valid {background-color: green;}
```

```html
<input id="auth_user_password" name="password" type="text" autocomplete="off" pattern="(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}" value="" placeholder="min 6 chars">
```

Comment: That works. Is there reason why the pattern requires a minimum length condition? Is this because of the type password?

Comment: it will always match, test it on https://regex101.com